# How the transaction history of an account including the amounts sent/received in the transaction be viewed using horizon?

Tags: transactions, assets, horizon

By checking transactions using something like:

```
https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/accounts/GBMTGMQXBXZS5XJROQQOZB7TU4ACBIXTJJEG7WTXP4ZEARPGQGDWHWIS/transactions?order=desc&limit=100
```

I get JSON of transactions. But nowhere in it is the name/ID of the asset being transacted nor the amount of the asset.

I'm looking to be able to output a history of a user's transaction history with our assets but struggling to find what can do this.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Transactions` are containers which contain `operations`.

`Operations` are what you're looking for.

Try hitting https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/accounts/GBMTGMQXBXZS5XJROQQOZB7TU4ACBIXTJJEG7WTXP4ZEARPGQGDWHWIS/operations?order=desc&limit=100 instead.